# Fill a list of objects with LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have a table which I created, and I inserted it to

```
var CurrTable;
```

The table looks like this:

```
SaleID | ProductID | ProductName

  1    |     1     |    Book
  1    |     2     |  Notebook
  2    |     3     |   Guitar
  2    |     4     |   Piano
```

I have two classes, ProductInfo and SaleInfo:

```
public class ProductInfo
{
    int ProductID;
    string ProductName;
}

public class SaleInfo
{
    int SaleID;
    List<ProductInfo> products;
}
```

I just want to fill a list of SaleInfo (`List<SaleInfo>`) with the data...

The query I wrote looks like this:

```
List<SaleInfo> results = (from s in CurrTable.AsEnumerable()
                                      group s by new { s.SaleId} into g
                                      select new SaleInfo
                                      {
                                          SaleID = g.Key.SaleId,
                                          Products = (*...*)
                                      }).ToList();
```

But I don't know what to write in the `(*...*)`. I don't want to do another select, because I already have the data. I just want to fill the list inside the list of products, and that's the reason I used the group function.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you want your select clause to be:

```
select new SaleInfo
{
    SaleID = g.Key.SaleId,
    Products = g.Select(x => new ProductInfo { ProductID = x.ProductID,
                                               ProductName = x.ProductName })
                .ToList()
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to materialize it into a list? What if I want to keep it an IQueryable inside an IQueryable? Would that make sense? Would it be possible?

Comment: @LuisGouveia: Well you could always just not call `ToList`... but whether that would do what you want is hard to say without knowing more about your context.

Comment: God bless you! I've been working on it the entire week! Now i can rest a little! :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select new SaleInfo()
        {
            SaleID=g.Key.SaleId,
            products=g.Select (x =>new ProductInfo(){
              ProductID=x.ProductID,ProductName=x.ProductName}).ToList()
        }
```

And if you should be able to access your properties. I would change the classes to this:

```
public class ProductInfo
{
    public int ProductID;
    public string ProductName;
}

public class SaleInfo
{
    public int SaleID;
    public List<ProductInfo> products;
}
```

Comment: You know if you are fine with the answer you might consider accepting it?